# Moderator Variable

Tags: interaction

I have a control variable firm size in my regression model. I want to examine the moderating role of the firm size. I added the firm type that is 1 for small-sized companies, 2 for medium-sized companies and 3 for large-sized companies. Now in this situation, should I remove firm size as the control variable and then run my model? Or do I have to keep that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: A typical way to test the moderating role of firm size would be to enter your predictor, firm size (as categorical), and their interaction term into your regression model. So don't remove it but add the interaction.

Comment: Thank you! My problem is that firm size is the log of the number of employees. For the moderator variable, I changed it to a categorical variable. But I am wondering whether I need to keep the log of the number of employees as control variable or I need to remove that and include firm type @Sointu

Comment: Right! Can't say for sure but my intuition would be to either take out the log-transformed variable for the interaction analysis, or use the log-transformed variable (instead of the categorical one) in the interaction term, depending on what exactly you want to find out. [This reply](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340253/how-to-create-the-interaction-term-when-one-of-the-variables-is-transformed) may be helpful?